# Is 90mm x 45mm a metric 4x2?

Tags: lumber

This is similar to [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/444/what-are-framing-dimensions-like-in-the-metric-world) question about metric measurements. In Australia, a common measurement is 90mm x 45mm for timber. A 4x2 would be (approx) 100mm x 50mm but, as I understand it, that is the milled rather than final measurement. Does the smaller metric size refer to the final measurement or does have nothing to do with a 4x2?

Comment: Also [Why are 2"x4"'s really 1.5"x3.5"?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/2768/22)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit wider than a typical US 2x4, but likely equivalent.  A 2x4 that you get for building is 3.5"x1.5" so that would equate to 89x38mm.

Comment: 90x35 is also available - that would be closer to the 89x38mm you've quoted above. I dare say 90x45 is more useful since it maintains the 2:1 ratio.

Comment: In the sense of someone saying "a 2x4 is/isn't strong enough to do that" sure, 90x45 or 90x35 are equivalent. If you're trying to build a box you may need to tweak plans that care precisely how wide a 2x4 is.